# Center icon in Actionbar

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-styles

I want to insert a centered icon in Actionbar, but i have no idea what code that i need. anyone can help me?

**This is my code :**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step 1: create a custom layout in R.layout. directory, as you desire and then set the view 
to action bar

step 2:  Set the custom layout.

```
   ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customActionBar, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(customView );
```

Answer (score 0):

From your xml add ToolBar as below and set Icon to ImageView inside it.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Set toolbar as support action bar as you are doing.